# Is there is a way to fetch private contacts of all the users using the Notes C API?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Is there is a way to fetch private contacts of all the users using the Notes C API?

Consider like there are following users in domino server,
1. UserA (Admin User)
2. UserB
3. UserC

I was using the Notes C API to fetch contacts under the user.
`ProcessFormula("SELECT Form=Person", &FormulaHandle);` and after that using NSFSearch to extract contacts.

When I try to pull the contacts of UserA, UserB, UserC 
    All the contacts of UserA pulled but the private contacts of UserB and UserC are not pulled.

Is there any Notes API to fetch private contacts of all the users (UserB and UserC (which are marked as private under the users)) using UserA(admin) access?

Answer (score 0):

First thing: code reading databases on a server obviously can't read anything that exists only in a user's local address book replica, and it is possible for a user to create contacts that will never be stored on the server.

If it exists on the server, though, your code may need to run with Full Access Admin privileges in order to read data that is protected with a ReaderNames field. You haven't said how your code is running. If it is actually running as a server task on the same server where the database exists, it's probably just a matter of how you open the database. If it is running somewhere else, the id file that it is running under will have to be granted full access rights and the user (you?) will have to activate those rights for your current session before running the code. I'd point you to help pages describing the Full Access Administration feature, but due ot the IBM/HCL transition it's now hard to find reliable links to online help page versions.

Comment: In MyContacts and $Contacts view the private contacts for the users are exist(contacts stored in .nsf file).For a User I have granted "Full access administrator",From Domino Admin->Configuration tab->Security tab->Full access administrator field.After granted "Full access administrator" rights i was logging in Lotus Notes Client using the user which has Full access administrator rights.From the current session i was tried opening other users mail file and i am not able to see private contacts of other users even I have logged in using the user which has full access administrator rights.

Comment: User database is opened using nsfopendb function ,DBHANDLE ContactsDB = 0
User databases are opened using NSFDbOpen( "CN=Domino/O=oraginzation!!mail\\test", &ContactsDB);. From Lotus notes client itself the contacts marked private using Mark Private checkbox on contact creation are only visible to specific user admin also not able to view those contacts

Comment: While opening Domino Admin each time using Administration->Full Access Administration i can able to enable Full Access Administration on current session. Using that session i am able to see private contacts of all the users by opening Open Mail File Option available. But how can i do it the same thing in Lotus Notes Client ?

Comment: I am not aware of any API that enables Full Access Administration. I suspect that they have not published one because they do not want tools to be able to use it silently. They want the user to always know that they are enabling it.

Comment: If you can write your code as a server task instead of as a user program, I suspect that all you will need to do is drop the "CN=Domino/O=oraginzation!!" from the argument in your NSFDbOpen call in order to open the file in "local" mode, This bypasses security unless the "Enforce Consistent ACL" property is enabled in the NSF file's properties.

Comment: In Java i can see something like this NotesFactory.createSessionWithFullAccess(); to bypass readers field. This there any equivalent  functionality exist in C++ notesapi ?

Comment: There might be, but I'm not aware of any. Try searching the header files for any references to "FULLACCESS", "FULL_ACESS", "Full access" or any other variations you can think of. If it's there, maybe it will be referenced in a defined constant or a comment.